# Why does tee cause a warning in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I am writing a bash script and encountered a warning message when using the tee command. I have reduced my code to this line:

```
echo "hi" | tee >(tee)
```

It works well and "hi" is printed out. But it also produces this warning:

```
tee: /dev/fd/63: Not a directory
```

I get this warning only in Cygwin and not under Linux.

My question is why this warning is produced? I think the command is clean and working well?

Comment: It seems a race issue. On my W10 the outputs is "hi hi"

Comment: I can reproduce it only with bash. Works fine with zsh. Didn't try other shells.

Comment: Yes, it's a bash issue